# How can I control Google Chrome browser without Selenium, or other webdrivers?

Tags: c#, browser, automation, interop, dllimport

I'd like to develop a software, which can start Google Chrome events (like next page, previous page, go to a specific url, open a new tab etc...) without Selenium Webdriver. It's very important!!! I don't want to use Selenium, I'd like to control existing chrome processes. 
How can I do this with C# interop services? 
How can I fetch JavaScript code into my chrome browser, to solve this problem? 
Where can I find a tutorial about this? 
Which solution is the best?

Probably it's not a too complicated problem, but I tried a ton of google search keywords already, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control Chrome or any other application with [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)
(I use Automation Core with reference to *c:\Windows\system32\UIAutomationCore.dll*)

Use **Inspect** tool from SDK to see the hierarchy of controls and various properties

[IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-elementfromhandle) to get IUIAutomationElement from Chrome main window and so on (tested on Windows 10 in C# with Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169)